# Masked View Error in React Native Why it is happening again and again i need solution coders

Tags: reactjs, react-native

```
import React from 'react';
import { View, Text, StyleSheet } from 'react-native';
import { createNativeStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import { NavigationContainer } from '@react-navigation/native';
import { createStackNavigator } from '@react-navigation/stack';
import HomeScreen from './HomeScreen';

const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

function App() {
    return(
        <NavigationContainer>
            <Stack.Navigator>
                <Stack.Screen name = "Home" component={HomeScreen}/>
            </Stack.Navigator>
        </NavigationContainer>
    )
}
export default App;
```

Unable to resolve module @react-native-masked-view/masked-view from D:\React Native\SDR-Project\node_modules@react-navigation\elements\src\MaskedViewNative.tsx: @react-native-masked-view/masked-view could not be found within the project.

If you are sure the module exists, try these steps:

1. Clear watchman watches: watchman watch-del-all
2. Delete node_modules and run yarn install
3. Reset Metro's cache: yarn start --reset-cache
4. Remove the cache: rm -rf /tmp/metro-*
   6 |
   7 | type MaskedViewType =

> 8 |   typeof import('@react-native-masked-view/masked-view').default;
> |                  ^
> 9 |
> 10 | type Props = React.ComponentProps & {
> 11 |   children: React.ReactElement;

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ceOa4.png)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please Install this dependency.
`@react-native-community/masked-view` if it doesn;t work then install  `@react-native-masked-view/masked-view`

Read more on install react-navigation into your project here are a list of some dependencies that you must install in order to run the application

```
npm install react-native-reanimated react-native-gesture-handler react-native-screens react-native-safe-area-context @react-native-community/masked-view
```

Comment: Mr. Aftab Amin thank you so much brother i was looking for this solution from two days now i got it thanks again.

Comment: Changing the dependency to "@react-native-masked-view/masked-view" resolved the issue.